# JSON Image View Showing Object at same Index

Tags: ios, arrays, json, indexing, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView in side a UIView, which displays an object @"photos" in a JSON Array as such: http://topmobiletrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/screen568x568-14.jpeg

My NSLog tells me that all the objects have been parsed correctly. But the UIImageViews inside UIViews show the same image, I believe it is the first object [0]. I need to have the views show each image for all of the objects for the @"photos" key.

Here is my code for my ViewController.m:

. . .

```
@interface ViewController ()



{

   NSInteger index;

}

//@property (nonatomic, weak)NSURL *imageURL;



@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize menuButton;
@synthesize myImage;
@synthesize priceLabel;

-(void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];



NSURL *bburl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.suchandsuch.com/api/sites"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:bburl];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:bburl];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithURL:bburl completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"%@", response);

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:location];

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

    NSString *imageURLString = [[[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"sites"] objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"photo"];


   NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[imageURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"sites : %@", imageURLString);


   NSArray *sitesArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"sites"];


    NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:sitesArray];

    for (NSDictionary *item in sitesArray) {

        MyObject *current = [MyObject alloc];
        current.name = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
        current.url = [item objectForKey:@"url"];
        current.price = [item objectForKey:@"price"];
        current.photo = [item objectForKey:@"photo"];



       [photos addObject:current];
        NSLog(@"%@", current.photo);

       }


        for (MyObject *photo in photos)

    {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

            UIView *dView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,30,258,229)];

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
           imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];

            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 258, 229);

           //Get image from url
           [self.imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL];

           //[self.myImage addSubview:imageView];

           [dView addSubview:imageView];
           [self.view addSubview:dView];
          // priceLabel.text = [[[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"sites"] objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"price"];

           });
        }


   }];

        [task resume];

}
```

Comment: Maybe a for loop could do the trick?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code.

1. You are adding both NSURL and name string to the photos array but when reading you are expecting all of them to be photos. 
   I would recommend create a data structure called Photo which contains

@interface PhotoClass :NSObject

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *price

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *photo;
@end
```

That way you can do the following when parsing your data.

```
PhotoClass *current = [PhotoClass alloc];
current.name = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
current.url = [item objectForKey:@"url"];
current.price = [item objectForKey:@"price"];
current.photo = [item objectForKey:@"photo"];

// Add to array
[photos addObject:current];
```

And then when you are ready to display use the url from each PhotoClass object.

The next issue in your code is with the image view setup. First of all You will need to create as many ImageViews. each one needs to be offset to the other can be visible behind that image. Plus the image view seems to be getting set in many diff ways. Is that just a typo? :

```
for (PhotoClass *photo in photos)
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

        UIView *dView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,258,229)];

        // The frame of each of the frames needs to be offset a little .. 
        // so you need to figure out how to calculate that for each image.
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photo.url]];
       [dView addSubview:imageView];
       [self.view addSubview:dView];
    ....

    }];
}
```

At the end of the loop you should have as many image views in view as objects in photos.

Disclaimer - code not compiled and typed directly into stackoverflow browser

Comment: Just tried it. The image views still display the same image. I'm not sure why this is happening. Thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: Where is index getting it's value? You need to show all the code .. What do u mean by it's not letting me remove objectatindex..

Comment: I mean I tried to remove objectatindex from NSString * imageURLString = [[[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"sites"]objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"photo"];

Comment: you need to know how the data is stored in your dictionary and then you have to read is appropriately.. rather than trial and error.. what does dataDictionary contain?

Comment: what does sitesArray look like.. ? Lets move this here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59036/imageissue.  Why are you still doing this - UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
           imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];  This is erroneous because you are creating the image THREE times

Comment: It says I don't have enough reputations to chat. :( email maybe?

Comment: Great news! I fixed it! :) I just deleted the extra for loop just before the dispatch! Thanks a million for helping me!! Wish I could give you +1!

Comment: Great!! Well done.. Actually u CAN 1 up my answer if u like ;)

Comment: It says I need 15 reputations to +1. I think I have like 5 now. :(